# Why Google displays search results all the cracks when appended by "94FBR" keyword in search query?

Tags: google, search-engines, google-search

I found on the internet that if you mention the software name and just add `94FBR` keyword to your search query  Google displays the results of all the cracks etc. for that software .

Refer to the image for better understanding. 
[image]

So I was just curious to know what does this happen and does `94FBR` has a special meaning?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not **[about a website you control](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)**.

Comment: @JohnConde : can you tell, posting this question on which stack exchange site will be good ?, or even better if you can migrate it there. -Thanks

Comment: @Shiva Just curious... what produces the blue bar in your search results?

Comment: @w3d I think it's PageRank Browser Addon. That's why its showing high for Facebook and low for other sites ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
does 94FBR has a special meaning?
```

`94FBR` was part of a Microsoft Office 2000 **product key** that was released on the internet that bypassed Microsoft's activation system. Google can also show results based on the synonyms of the searched query so it's highlighting **Windows 8** and  **Crack** when you searched '**Windows 8 94FBR**'

Comment: but it even works for non Microsoft product you can even try "Photoshop 94FBR" or any other software name.

Comment: @Shiva Yeah! It's showing because Google is considering 94FBR as Product key. Cracks can also called as keys so its highlighting crack when you searched 94FBR with any software name :)